# Rails 3 - Model structure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, structure

I would like to have nice and clean structure in my Rails App.

Now I have 4 files in models folder: Post, PostTranslation, PostCategory and PostCategoryTranslation.

This is my post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :image_cache, :remove_image, :post_category_ids, :post_categories_attributes, :post_translations_attributes
  validates :post_translations, :post_categories, presence: :true

  translates :name, :content
  has_many :post_translations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_translations, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This is post_translation.rb

```
 class PostTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :locale, :name, :content
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 255 }, presence: true
  validates :content, :locale, presence: true

  belongs_to :post

end
```

What should I do? What's the best practice? Make post folder and move translation into this folder and create sub model? Like this: `class Translation < Post`

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

The main *Best Practice* here is to define your domain model properly, and this holds good regardless of Rails.

You need to decide what relation do `Post` and `PostTranslation` have with each other. If `PostTranslation < Post`, then `belongs_to :post` should probably not be there inside `PostTranslation`.

Once you have a clearer modelling, put all the classes in `models` folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added namespace Blog..

Now I have these files

```
blog/post.rb - Blog::Post
blog/post/translation.rb - Blog::Post::Translation
blog/category.rb - Blog::Category
blog/category/translation.rb - Blog::Category::Translation


class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :translations, :categories, presence: true
    translates :name, :content
    accept_nested_attributes_for :translations, allow_destroy: true
end


class Blog::Post::Translation < Globalize::ActiveRecord::Translation 
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :locale, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :blog_post_id }
end
```